# intex modem not recognised in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, usb-modem

I am trying to connect intex USB modem to access most awaited internet after installing Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and there is no response after inserting modem in USB port, even though I installed modem managerGUI, it didn't work.

Could anybody please tell me how to connect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your modem LED is not blinking but showing this "mobile broadband" in available network list. in that case you have to manually set your mobile broadband. 
go to system setting then click on network. in network list there will show "mobile broadband". click on it, in right side there there is "network" with a blank space. click on it. now click on add new connection. give your country name and service provider name and follow any other steps. 
may be that after connected to your network, still LED may not blink.
i have intex modem and i had the same problem.

Comment: Intexmodem LED is not blinking but not showing this "mobile broadband" in available network list,for first time it showed mobile broadband option and then not appeared.In system settings/network options,in network list there is no "mobile broadband" option.I tried GnomePPP but here also it is not detecting the modem.In top right network ribbon of desktop i can't find any mobile broadband option  here i find 1)intex modem not detecting  2)need to set mobile broadband connection on ,i'm new to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS  please give suggetions to connect internet

Answer (score 0):

if there is no modem broadband connection shows in available network list. you have to install INTEX modem installer. you can do it by following steps.  open the intex modem from launcher.open Linux folder. there will be INTEx SPEED 3G installer.deb file. click on that file to install. while installing it there will show you a msg. of package bad quality. click on ignore and install. after installing . modem broadband connection will show in network list.